# How can I align numeric input right and text input left with CSS?

Tags: css

If I have two `<input type="text" ...` and I know that one should accept text and the other a numeric value (and will check that in PHP when validating the form), can I align the contents of the text box left & the contents of the numeric box right using CSS?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The latest update for this can be done like below

1. `<input type="number" />` for Numbers Type of text fields.
2. `<input type="text"/>` for text type of input fields

Then you can make use of CSS.

```
input[type=number] {
  text-align:right;
}


input[type=text] {
  text-align:left;
}
```

This would help you a lot if you add more fields to your webpage.

Answer (score 26):

```
<style type="text/css">
     .right { text-align: right; } </style>

<input type="text" /> <input type="text" class="right"/>
```

Comment: +1 an dthe answer. D'oh! I had put the class on the enclosing DIV

Comment: It'd be a better idea to name the class something like "text" rather than "right". If in a week he wants to change it to left align he just changes it in one place in the CSS rather than fixing the classname everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just correction regarding CSS external file:

```
input.right{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue